# Laravel 5.8 not respecting $retryAfter specified in job class

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.8

I have a Laravel with some Jobs that are usually very quick to run. Hence I have configured my default retry_after in config/queue.php to 20 seconds

```
'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 20,
        ],
```

I do however have one type of Jobs that can take much longer, up to a few minutes, so I have upgraded to Laravel 5.8 to be able to specify a retry-after parameter specific to this class:

```
class LongJob implements ShouldQueue {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $timeout = 600;
    public $tries = 3;
    public $retryAfter = 610;
```

However, when I dispatch a LongJob to the queue, I find in my logs that the job is called twice, i.e., at dispatch, and then 20 seconds after.

Can you think of any reason why Laravel would not "see" my $retryAfter option - which from what I understand is supposed to override the global setting?

EDIT: after further testing, it seems that $retryAfter and retry_after do not work exactly the same... From what I've tried:

- a job will be attempted again after `retry_after` seconds, regardless of whether it's still running from a previous attempt
- when a job fails and is released back into the queue, it will attempted again after `$retryAfter` seconds

Hence in my case, correct values would be:

```
retry_after = 610; //As long as the longest timeout is + small buffer
$retryAfter = 5; //I'd like my job to be re-attempted quickly after it fails
```

Not sure if a bug or a feature...

Comment: Did you restart your queue after you added `$retryAfter` to your job?

Comment: Yes :( nice to point it out though, I've made that mistake in the past..

Comment: Which queue worker are you using?

Comment: The "default" queue worker with supervisor keeping it running

Comment: Sorry, I meant  what connection are you using i.e. redis, db, beanstalkd, sqs etc.?

Comment: Oh, using the db driver. I've edited my original post with additional info, it seems maybe the "retry after" option does not work as expected (or at least as I expected it to work)

Comment: Can you let me know exactly what version of 5.8 you have installed?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.8.27 sir!

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Not really no. The "workaround" I ended up adopting was to set retry_after in the queue driver to a long value (longer than the timeout value of my longest job), and set a $retryAfter parameter individually in each job

Comment: any solution ?? i also have same question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63816367/getting-illuminate-queue-maxattemptsexceededexception-in-laravel-jobs @Buno