# How can i set custom retry_after for long running jobs | laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Question: How to customize long-running job without attempting multiple time after each retry_after seconds?

I have one job which will take 1 to 3 hours to run,
I already created job-based on laravel documentation, here is my job file.

```
<?php


namespace App\Modules\Csv\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use League\Csv\Reader;
use Phone;

/**
 * A single excel import job, which can be pushed on to a queue
 */
class UploadCsvDataInTable extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels, Dispatchable,Queueable;

    public $timeout = 172800;
    /**
     * The excel to import
     *
     * @var App\BulkUpload
     */
    protected $csvUpload;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param App\FeedImport
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(CsvUpload $csvUpload)
    {
        $this->csvUpload = $csvUpload;
    }

    public function handle()
    {

        app(CsvUploadService::class)->uploadCsv($this->csvUpload);

    }
}
```

here is Laravel [document](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout) to specify a timeout for jobs.

here is code for how I am calling that job.

```
UploadCsvDataInTable::dispatch($csvUpload)->onConnection('redis')->onQueue('low');
```

my command for queue:work In supervisor.

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=high,low,default --sleep=3 --tries=3
```

here is my configuration for queue & horizon

```
// horizon.php
 'production' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue'      => ['high', 'default', 'low'],
                'balance'    => 'simple',
                'processes'  => 6,
                'tries'      => 3,
            ],
 ],

  //queue.php

  'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],
```

I can see because of retry_after my job is attempting multiple time and after reaching 3 try as per horizon configuration its throwing MaxAttemptsExceededException.

if I increase $timeout to 24 hours I am getting duplicate records in my db as retry_after is attempting that job multiple time.

is there any way I can set custom retry_after for this job?

Comment: after exactly 1 hour the job stops working, signals timeout? could it be a server side issue?

Comment: @Vladan there is no issue on the server I think its because of configuration its not taking timeout from job file

Comment: not sure if helpful but try adding `'timeout' => 172800` below` `'tries'      => 3`, in horizon.php `supervisor-1` array

Comment: @Vladan i did now i my job is not getting time out but records in db are coming mulple time it means job is processing many times

Comment: then put tries to 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created another connection for long-running jobs and its working properly for me.

created new supervisor connection in horizon.php for long running process

```
'supervisor-long-running' => [
                'connection' => 'redis-long-processes',
                'queue' => 'long-running',
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 3,
                'tries' => 1,
                'timeout' => 86000 // should be shorter than retry_after out
]
```

and new redis connection in queue.php

```
 'redis-long-processes' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => 'long-running',
            'retry_after' => 86400,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],
```

in database.php added new queue for long running jobs.

```
'queue' => [
                [
                    'connection' => 'redis',
                    'queue'      => ['high', 'default', 'low','long-running'],
                    'balance'    => 'simple',
                    'processes'  => 6,
                    'tries'      => 3,
                    'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
                    'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
                ],
            ],
```

also don't forgot to call jobs using onConnection and onQueue to specify from which queue jobs should execute.

```
UploadDataInTable::dispatch($upload)->onConnection('redis-long-processes')->onQueue('long-running');
```

Comment: I got what you've done. Thank you Jigar . Also @Yevgeniy Afanasyev's solution fits with my situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

you don't need to set `retry_after`, you need to set tries to 1

```
public $tries = 1;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#max-attempts