# Laravel 7 , changing queue connection during runtime not working / horizon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

This is my config/queue.php

```
 'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
    'long_run' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 3600,
    ],
```

This is my config/horizon.php

```
 'environments' => [
    'production' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'processes' => 10,
            'tries' => 1,
        ],
    ],

    'local' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'processes' => 3,
            'tries' => 1,
        ],
    ],
],
```

This is the code I run on my controller, after I do php artisan horizon. It kinda feels like it redirects to the first connection instead, as it exactly times me out after 90 seconds, instead of 3600. I did try php artisan config:cache and restarted horizon, but still the issue persists

```
 dispatch(new doSomethingJob($path,auth()->user()))->onConnection('long_run');
```

Changing retry_after on my redis connection will fix the issue, but is not my desired result.

Comment: On my .env file, I'm connected on the first connection 'redis', but I don't want to use it for long queue jobs, only short ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040705/15182404
Seems like I forgot to add the supervisor

```
    'supervisor-long-running' => [
                'connection' => 'long_run',
                'queue' => 'default',
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 3,
                'tries' => 1,
                'timeout' => 86000 // should be shorter than retry_after out
]
```

Comment: Please accept this answer so that we would know that this question is solved. Thanks!

Comment: Have to wait for the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you had to set the driver before calling the dispatch. Can you try :

```
$job = (new Job(…))->onQueue('driver');
$this->dispatch($job);
```

Comment: Won't work. Here's an example of laravel docs. 
ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast)>onConnection('sqs')->onQueue('processing');